# How to use a style tag in react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tags, styles

```
<script src="https://pie-meister.github.io/PieMeister-with-Progress.min.js"></script>
    
              <pie-chart className="nested" offset="top">
                 <style>
                  path {
            stroke-linecap: round;
            stroke-width: 90;
                  }
                  [color1] {
            stroke: #BFBDB2;
            stroke-width: 50;
                  }
                  [color2] {
            stroke: #26BDD8;
            stroke-width: 60;
                  }
                  [color3] {
            stroke: #824BF1;
                  }
                  [part="path"]:not([y]) {
                    stroke: #BFBDB2;
                    stroke-width: 60;
            opacity: 0.4;
                  }
                </style>
```

I was using this library pie-master and it had styled attributes as shown above.
I want to implement the similar in react.

Answer (score 0):

> <Component style={{color: "red"}} />

Answer (score 0):

In React, you have to pass the style attribute to the component as an object. Let's say your component name is PieChart, you can pass style attribute like this

```
   <PieChart style={{ border: '1px solid red', fontSize: '1rem' }}> 
   </PieChart>
   <div style={{ border: '1px solid red', fontSize: '1rem' }}></div>
```

For more [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style)

Answer (score 0):

I tried these too, they were working for other elements but not for this graph.
However i found a solution.

```
<script src="https://pie-meister.github.io/PieMeister-with-Progress.min.js"></script>
import React from 'react'
const style = ` <pie-chart class="nested" offset="top">
<style>
path {
stroke-linecap: round;
stroke-width: 90;
}
[color1] {
stroke: #BFBDB2;
stroke-width: 50;
}
[color2] {
stroke: #26BDD8;
stroke-width: 60;
}
[color3] {
stroke: #824BF1;
}
[part="path"]:not([y]) {
stroke: #BFBDB2;
stroke-width: 60;
opacity: 0.4;
}
</style>
<slice color1 size="100%" radius="200"><!--No label--></slice>
<slice color1 size="88%" radius="200" y="65"><tspan> $size</tspan></slice>
<slice color2 size="100%" radius="100"> </slice>
<slice color2 size="40%" radius="100" y="165"><tspan> $size</tspan>     </slice>
<slice color3 size="100%" radius="0"> </slice>
<slice color3 size="10%" radius="0" y="265"><tspan> $size</tspan></slice>
</pie-chart>`
export default function Styles() {
return (
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:style}}/>   
)
}
```